# Independent probabilities of four events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have four boxes: $A, B, C, D$. I throw one ball at each of the four boxes, independently. I have a $\frac{3}{10}$ chance of making it into $A$. A $\frac{2}{27}$ chance of making it into $B$. A $0$ percent chance of making it into $C$. And finally a $\frac{6}{7}$ chance of making it into D.

What's the probability that I make it into exactly 0, 1, 2, or 3 boxes? The chance I make it into at least 1 box?

My thinking:

For the probability that I make it into at least 1 box, that's just the sum of the probabilities of making it into exactly 1, 2, 3, and 4 boxes, right?

Can I use the probability mass function to solve the rest?

Comment: Simpler method:  Find the chance you get into *zero* boxes.  Then the chance you get into at least *one* box is simply 1.0 minus that chance.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork is the probability of getting into 0 $(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{25}{27})(1)(\frac{1}{7})$??

Comment: Yep!...........